# How to determine which font is being used to render a specific character in Terminal

Tags: terminal, font

Terminal is rendering 0x209A (a subscript "p") in a nice way when I use `cat` to look a file that contains that character.  Terminal has been configured to use Inconsolata as its default font, but I'm fairly confident Inconsolata doesn't have that code-point specifically. Indeed, if I use the "Show emoji & symbols" dropdown, the Unicode table doesn't list a font for that code-point at all.  But still, Terminal is doing a good job of showing me the character, and the tabular presentation in the dropdown does show it as well.  How do I find out what font is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy/paste it into TextEdit & see what font it switches to, or type 209A into the search box in the Emoji & Symbols viewer & use that to enter the character.

[image]

Deja Vu is a common unicode replacement, as it a very comprehensive font.

Comment: In my case, the verdict was `System Font`.